# AddMonitor 183 error

Tags: c#, printing, virtual, port, spooler

There is a simple code:

```
[DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "AddMonitorA", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern bool AddMonitor([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string Name, Int32 Level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] MONITOR_INFO_2 mi2);

public static int MonitorInstaller(out string errorMessage)
    {
        int ret = 0;
        byte* pMonitor = GetBytePtr(Globals.PortMonitorName);
        errorMessage = null;

        ret = IsMonitorInstalled(pMonitor, false);
        Loger.WriteLog("IsMonitorInstaled: {0}", ret);
        if (ret != 0)
        {
            Loger.WriteLog("Test_point_01");
            errorMessage = "Monitor is already installed.";
            return 1;
        }

        bool delRes = DeleteMonitor(null, null, Globals.PortMonitorName);
        Loger.WriteLog("Delete result: {0}", delRes);


        MONITOR_INFO_2 mi2 = new MONITOR_INFO_2();

        mi2.pName = Globals.PortMonitorName;
        mi2.pEnvironment = "Windows NT x86";
        mi2.pDLLName = Globals.MonitorFile;

        Loger.WriteLog("mi2 data:");
        Loger.WriteLog("pName: {0}", mi2.pName);
        Loger.WriteLog("pDLLName: {0}", mi2.pDLLName);

        bool bRet = AddMonitor(null, 2, mi2);
        Loger.WriteLog("AddMonitor result: {0}", bRet);
        if (!bRet)
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Loger.WriteLog("AddMonitor erro: {0}", errorCode);
            errorMessage = new Win32Exception(errorCode).Message;
            return errorCode;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

The AddMonitor function allways sets 183 errorcode: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. But there are no such monitor. Give me any ideas for it.
P.S. Application running with administator account, there is no antivirus on the test virtual mashine and the windows firewall is off.

Comment: Is your IsMonitorInstalled function working correctly? Assuming you calling EnumMonitors and the pMonitor parameter you are passing to your function is the pMonitor for EnumMonitors then it would appear you are doing something incorrectly.

It is easy enough to check manually if your monitor is installed, just look for an entry in the following registry key.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors

Comment: Also you are not setting the Environment parameter on your DeleteMonitor call so it will default to what ever your operating system is set to. If your local environment is not 32 bit then the above code will not be deleting the monitor that you add if you run the code again.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors have no my monitor. Can I add the monitor, just write a needed values for this registry key?

Comment: Yes you can simply add the appropriate registry keys, however if you do it that way you will need to restart the spooler service for it to pick up the monitor.